# how to programming pre / in order traversal without recursion in python

Tags: python, traversal, inorder, preorder

here is my code about postorder_nonrecursive.
I want to know preorder and inorder like this code.
please help me!

```
def postorder_nonrecursive(self):
        if self == None:
            return
        stack = [[self,0]] 

        while len(stack) > 0:
            node, state = stack[-1]

            if state == 2:
                yield node
                stack.pop()
            else:
                child = (node.getLeft() if state == 0 else node.getRight())
                stack[-1][1] += 1

                if child != None:
                    stack.append([child,0])
```

Comment: I've no idea what your question actually is. Please read [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, I mean that I want to know preorder and inorder traversal without recursion python code using my postorder code.

Comment: That's still not really a question, and certainly not an on-topic one here.